# pySerial modem result codes

Tags: python, pyserial, modem

I'm using pySerial and python 2.7 on a Debian box. I'm writing python code to control a USRobotics USB USR5637 modem. I want to check the responses from the modem for issues/errors but I'm getting anomalous results from my code. I've written some basic code for testing. I do have the phone line disconnected so I can see a result code of "NO CARRIER." If anyone has access to pySerial and a modem I would appreciate any help that can be provided.

I created the following code for testing:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=5)
ser.write("ATE0\r")  # Attention - Echo disable
response =  ser.read(4)
print "ATE0 %s" % response
ser.write("ATX0\r")  # Attention - Echo disable
response2 =  ser.read(8)
print "ATX0 %s" % response2
ser.write("ATDT411\r")  # Attention - Dail - Tone - 411
response3 =  ser.read(32)
print "ATDT %s" % response3
ser.write("ATH\r")  # Attention - Hang up line
response4 =  ser.read(16)
print "ATH %s" % response4
ser.write("ATZ\r")  # Reset
response5 =  ser.read(16)
print "ATZ %s" % response5
print "================================================="
print "%s %s %s %s %s" % (response, response2, response3, response4, response5)
ser.close()
```

The response I get is:

```
ATE0 
OK
ATX0 

OK

ATDT 
ATH 
NO CARRIER

ATZ 
OK

=================================================

OK 

OK

NO CARRIER

OK
```

My questions are:

1. What is the number in ser.read(4) or ser.read(8). Is it a timeout?
2. I don't seem to get the "NO CARRIER" until after the ATH section of the code. I would expect to get it directly after the ATDT section.
3. Why do I end up with only four results?
4. Why the anomalous spacing in the printed results?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ser.read(4)` means to read 4 bytes from the serial port. You have configured a 5 second timeout with your constructor call:

```
serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=5)
```

so `ser.read(4)` may return less than 4 characters. Use `timeout=None` for a blocking read in which case it won't return until exactly 4 characters have been received.

You are getting the weird spacing because each response sent by the modem ends in a CR character (and it may be be a CR/LF pair.)

You might find it easier to interact with the modem using this `getline()` function:

```
def getline(ser):
  buf = ""
  while True:
    ch = ser.read(1)
    if ch == '\r':    # or perhaps '\n'
      break
    buf += ch
  return buf
```

As for #2, I believe you are getting "NO CARRIER" due to the ATH command you sent.

See the "Making a call" section in this MS Support Note [(link)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164659)

According to the note sending a hangup command will result in a NO CARRIER response.
The modem is probably still trying to establish a connection when you send the ATH.

Comment: This solves question 1 and 4. Thanks. I can tell the modem to return a single value code instead of verbose text and this above code will do nicely.

Comment: Answer updated. If you find any of it useful an upvote would be appreciated.